# how to display two list in display tag struts2

Tags: struts2

how to display two list in display tag struts2

```
<display:table  id="employeeList" name="employeeList" requestURI="/viewEmployeeAction">
<display:column property="employeeNo" title="EMPLOYEE_NO" sortable="true"/>

<display:column property="firstName+' '+lastName" title="EMP_NAME" sortable="true"/>

<display:column property="joiningDate" title="JOINING_DATE"  sortable="true"/>
<display:setProperty name="paging.banner.placement" value="bottom"/>
</display:table>
```

problem on line 3, i want to concat two fields in one column and display   it.

any one give me solution Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution would be to write

```
<display:column title="EMP_NAME" >
    <c:out value="${employeeList.firstName}"/> <c:out value="${employeeList.lastName}"/>
</display:column>
```

The problem of this is that it cannot be sortable.

To solve this you may need to create a new getter in your Employee class like this:

```
public String getFullName(){
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
}
```

and then use it with:

```
<display:column property="fullName" title="EMP_NAME" sortable="true"/>
```

I haven't tested this second solution but I think it will do the trick and hopefuly be sortable.

Comment: are u know any solution how to take more than one list in display tag. In my above example i have used only list instead i require two or more lists.    <display:table  id="employeeList" name="employeeList,positionList" requestURI="/viewEmployeeAction"> I have tried this many times i have no any solution...

Comment: I think that isn't possible. You could merge your two lists into one and then display both of them using displaytag. Note that you may require inheritance to do that. You may also want to consider the posibility of display first one list and later the other one independently.

Answer (score 0):

```
<display:table name="<%=terminalList%>"  class="displaytagstyle" id="terminaltable" sort="list" style="width:100%">    

<display:column title="TERMINAL NUMBER" href="<%=editPath%>" paramId="paramid" paramProperty="trmnum" sortable="true">
                                    ${terminaltable.trmnum} ${terminaltable.unLocationCode1}
 </display:column>
```